# How to get back the co-ordinate points corresponding to the intensity points obtained from a faster r-cnn object detection process?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection

As a result of the faster r-cnn method of object detection, I have obtained a set of boxes of intensity values(each bounding box can be thought of as a 3D matrix with depth of 3 for rgb intensity, a width and a height which can then be converted into a 2D matrix by taking gray scale) corresponding to the region containing the object. What I want to do is to obtain the corresponding co-ordinate points in the original image for each cell of intensity inside of the bounding box. Any ideas how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you got an R-CNN model that outputs cropped pieces of the input image and you now want to trace those output crops back to their coordinates in the original image.

What you can do is simply use a patch-similarity-measure to find the original position.
Since the output crop should look **exactly** like itself in the original image, just use Pixel-based distance:

[image]

Find the place in the image with the smallest distance (should be zero) and from that you can find your desired coordinates.

In python:

```
d_min = 10**6
crop_size = crop.shape
for x in range(org_image.shape[0]-crop_size[0]):
    for y in range(org_image.shape[1]-crop_size[1]):
        d = np.abs(np.sum(np.sum(org_image[x:x+crop_size[0],y:y+crop_size[0]]-crop)))
        if d <= d_min:
            d_min = d
            coord = [x,y]
```

**However**, your model should have that info available in it (after all, it crops the output based on some coordinates). Maybe if you add some info on your implementation.